# Add a spam flag also for questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, spam

There's a flag as spam for an answer (the first option), but for example, for this [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480286/can-anybody-tell-me-about-indian-fashion-accessories-fairs-in-2018) which is obviously spam, there's no spam option in the flag options dialog, and I need to make it off-topic which is a general option.

I think a spam flag should be added for questions also.

BTW: I don't think there should be an automatic comment with my user

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's spam

Comment: The flag already exists for questions.

Comment: @SurajRao if you mean the following, I think it's too broad: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. `

Comment: No, there is a "spam" option at the top of the "flag" box. You are looking at the "close" box. https://i.stack.imgur.com/clCTx.png

Comment: What do you mean by *"I don't think there should be an automatic comment with my user"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was confused with close options, so I didn't expect flagging as spam will create a comment with my user

Comment: You have thought on spam as close reason? I think it is not a close reason, it is a flag (because spam questions shouldn't be closed, they should be deleted and sawn with salt).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a "spam" option when flagging questions. In fact, it's the first option in the dialog - see the [screenshot from the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

The question you linked to was already auto-deleted since it was flagged as spam by six users, including myself.

**EDIT:**
Based on the comments to the question, I think the problem may have been you've opened the "close" dialog instead of the "flag" dialog, which is located to its right.